# Rational function - domain and vertical asymptote

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Consider the function:
$f(x)=\frac{2x^4+7x^3-7x^2-3x+1}{x^3-x^2+x-1}.$

When looking for domain, the denominator $x^3-x^2+x-1$ can not be zero. So $f(x)$ is undefined when $x=1.$

But when simplifying given function I get:

$f(x)=\frac{2x^4+7x^3-7x^2-3x+1}{x^3-x^2+x-1}=\frac{(x-1)(2x-1)(x^2+4x-1)}{(x-1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{(2x-1)(x^2+4x-1)}{x^2+1}$.

Now domain seems to change, since $x^2+1>0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Does the domain change when simplifying given expression?

Also, when determinating the vertical asymptote, we look for domain. I was thinking that since $x^2+1>0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that given function doesn't have any undefined points so vertical asymptote doesn't exist. 
Or do I need to consider first domain and look for the limit of function as $x$ approaches $1^+$ or $1^-$?

Thank you!

Comment: Note:  $x/x$ is not defined when $x=0$ even though generally $x/x=1$

Comment: Does that mean that domain will still be the same, $D_f = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}.$
And I still need to look for the limit of $f(x)$ when $x$ approaches $1^+$ and $1^-$?

Comment: consider $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ which is not defined for $x=4$ . But by simplifying  ,we get  $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2} = \frac{x-2}{x+2}$ which is defined for all $x$

Comment: Yes, the domain changes because when you "simplify" the function it is no longer the same function.  Taking J.W. Tanner's simpler example, x/x= 1 for all x **except** x= 0.  The graph of y= 1 is a horizontal straight line.  The graph of y= x/x is that same line **except** that the point (0, 1) is missing- there is a "hole" there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$f(x)=\frac{(x-1)(2x-1)(x^2+4x-1)}{(x-1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{(2x-1)(x^2-4x-1)}{x^2+1}$$ only if $$x\neq 1$$
There is a whole in this function at $x=1$

Comment: Thanks, I got it! Now, to find vertical asymptote, I must consider the limit of function, right?

Comment: Now you must compute $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$